# Can one compute the nth Fibonacci number in time O(n) or O(1)? Why?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, fibonacci

I asked myself if one can compute the nth Fibonacci number in time **O(n) or O(1)** and why?

Can someone explain please?

Comment: How does the number of digits representing *the nth Fibonacci number* grow as a function of *n*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is called [Binet's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula), or sometimes, **incorrectly**, De Moivre's Formula (the real De Moivre's formula is [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), but De Moivre *did* discover Binet's formula before Binet), and involves the golden ratio Phi. The mathematical reasoning behind this (see link) is a bit involved, but doable:

[image]

While it is an approximate formula, Fibonacci numbers are integers -- so, once you achieve a high enough precision (depends on *n*), you can just approximate the number from Binet's formula to the closest integer.

Precision however depends on constants, so you basically have two versions, one with float numbers and one with double precision numbers, with the second also running in constant time, but slightly slower. For *large* n you will need an **arbitrary precision number library**, and those have processing times that do depend on the numbers involved; as observed by @MattTimmermans, you'll then probably end up with a O(log^2 n) algorithm. This should happen for large enough values of *n* that you'd be stuck with a large-number library no matter what (but I'd need to test this to be sure).

Otherwise, the Binet formula is mainly made up of two exponentiations and one division (the three sums and divisions by 2 are probably negligible), while the recursive formula mainly employs function calls and the iterative formula uses a loop. While the first formula is O(1), and the other two are O(n), the actual times are more like *a*, *b n + c* and *d n + e*, with values for a, b, c, d and e that depend on the hardware, compiler, implementation etc. . With a modern CPU it is very likely that *a* is not too larger than *b* or *d*, which means that the O(1) formula should be faster for almost every *n*. But most implementations of the iterative algorithm start with

```
if (n < 2) {
        return n;
}
```

which is very likely to be faster for n = 0 and n = 1. I feel confident that Binet's formula is faster for any n beyond the single digits.

Comment: This ignores the question of how long it takes to compute the value of the expression.

Comment: Because the required precision increases with *n*, this takes at least O(log^2 n) time.

Comment: so, because of the golden ratio, it is possible in O(n) ?

Comment: @Larry not quite... O(n) is always possible due to the definition of a Fibonacci sequence (you can always get F(n) from F(n-1) and F(n-2) in O(1)). Then, this particular expression can be rewritten and be immediately solvable whatever n, thus O(1). The golden ratio is a different result of the same calculation.

Comment: @LSerni so the following statement "One can compute the nth Fibonacci number in time O(n)." is true, because of the definition of a Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking about the recursive method, think of building the sequence from the bottom up, starting at 1+1.

Comment: Whats the difference - recursive or iterative - O(N) should be obvious in either case, right?

Comment: @BitTickler no in recursive case, you are solving one Fibonacci number many times. Take a look if you want to compute the 4th number, you should compute second and third. but to compute third, it's necessary to compute second and first.
so the second number is computed twice.

Comment: @BitTickler: since the recursive case performs `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)`, that would mean each call recurses in two extra, making it exponential.

Comment: This does not answer `Can one compute the nth Fibonacci number in time O(n) or O(1)?`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Depends on how you do the recursion. From Haskell wiki on fibonachi: ```haskell
Prelude> :{
Prelude| fib :: Int -> Int
Prelude| fib n = go n (0,1)
Prelude|     where
Prelude|         go n (a,b) | n == 0 = a
Prelude|                    | otherwise = go (n-1) (b, a+b)
Prelude| :}
```
See: https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a matrix `m` like this:

```
1    1
1    0
```

and calculate power n of it. then output `m^n[0,0]`.

Comment: This does not answer `Can one compute the nth Fibonacci number in time O(n) or O(1)?`

Comment: @greybeard actually it does. The (0,0)-th element of the exponentiated matrix will be the (n+1)-th Fibonacci number. Time complexity is O(n), but you can use a recursive function (m^n is m^n/2 * m^n/2 optionally multiplied by n to cope with odd values of n), and end up with O(log n).

Comment: @LSerni without the clarification on the bitwidth growth (what  greybeard asked in his first comment below OP) we cannot go to complexities as we do not know if basic operations are atomic O(1) or not.